# Codeigniter inline edit not working

Tags: codeigniter

I created the following code, but do not run. Can you help?

My Controller

```
public function updateDb()
  {
         //$this->load->model('user_m');                     
        $this->page_m->inline($_POST['file_description']);
         return;
  }
```

My Model

```
public function inline( $file_description, $id ){
$this->db->set($data)->where($this->$id, $page['file_description'])->update($this->file);
}
```

Form

```
<a href="#" id="file_description" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="<?php echo $file->file_description?>"><?php echo $file->file_description?></a>
```

Jquery

```
function showEdit(file_description) {
    $(file_description).css("background","#FFF");
} 
    function save(file_description) {
    $(file_description).css("background","#FFF url(<?php echo base_url('assets/img/loaderIcon.gif');?>loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/admin/page/updateDb",
        type: "POST",
        id   : '<?php echo $page->id;?>',
        name : 'file_description'   
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not passing the ID to your model which it requires.

```
public function inline( $file_description, $id ){...}



$this->page_m->inline($_POST['file_description'], $_POST['id']);
```

You could use $this->input->post() though...